# Set column value if row is between a date range

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have multiple date ranges which can overlap:

```
start_Jan, end_Jan = "2019-01-01", "2019-01-07"
start_Jan2, end_Jan2 = "2019-01-05", "2019-01-09"
start_Feb, end_Feb = "2019-02-15", "2019-02-18"
```

and a df with date in ISO 8601 as index.

```
           | runs
2019-01-01 | 0
2019-01-02 | 0
...
2019-01-05 | 0
2019-01-20 | 0
```

For every day that is between one of the date ranges it should add 1 to the "runs" column.

Desired output:

```
           | runs
2019-01-01 | 1
2019-01-02 | 1
...
2019-01-05 | 2
2019-01-20 | 0
```

Since I have quite a lot of date ranges which will grow on an irregular base best would be a way where I can just add a date range tuple to a list everytime I get a new one and just rerun the calculation.

Any easy way to do that with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
L = [(start_Jan,end_Jan), (start_Jan2,end_Jan2), (start_Feb, end_Feb )]
for s, e in L:
    df.loc[s:e] += 1
```

Another idea is use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) for Series for all tuples, joined together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and summed:

```
L = [(start_Jan,end_Jan), (start_Jan2,end_Jan2), (start_Feb, end_Feb )]

s = pd.concat([pd.Series(1, index=pd.date_range(s, e)) for s, e in L], axis=1).sum(axis=1)
print (s)
2019-01-01    1.0
2019-01-02    1.0
2019-01-03    1.0
2019-01-04    1.0
2019-01-05    2.0
2019-01-06    2.0
2019-01-07    2.0
2019-01-08    1.0
2019-01-09    1.0
2019-02-15    1.0
2019-02-16    1.0
2019-02-17    1.0
2019-02-18    1.0
dtype: float64

df = df['runs'].add(s, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pandas.date_range(start=start_jan, end=end_jan, freq='D')
```

will give you a DatetimeIndex covering each day between (inclusive) the start date and end date specified.